# Unexpected token f in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, json

I am looking to implement Zenvia's SMS API in our project. I'm using their manual that shows the following structure:

```
{
  "from": "5510999999999",
  "to": "55108888888888",
  "contents": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Hi Zenvia!"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using PHP to do this implementation. My code below:

```
public function SMS($telefone,$mensagem)
    {
        $method = 'POST';
        $from = '5511999999999';
        $to = '55'.$telefone;
        $msg = $mensagem;
        $body = [
            "from" => $from,
            "to" => $to,
            "contents" => [
                            "type" => "text",
                            "text" => $msg
                          ]          
       ];           
       $campos = http_build_query($body);
       $header = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'X-API-TOKEN: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"'
        );
        $url = 'https://api.zenvia.com/v2/channels/sms/messages';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $campos);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        $resposta = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump($resposta);
        if(curl_error($ch))
        {
            echo curl_error($ch);
            return curl_error($ch);
        }
        else
        {
            json_decode($resposta);
            
        }
  curl_close($ch);  
    }
}
```

But when I run, the following error appears:

> string(78) "{"code":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"Unexpected token f in
> JSON at position 0"}"

How do I fix it?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: http_build_query does not return json

Comment: Hello Dmitry MiksIr. Sorry, I don't know much about PHP with Json. What would be the best solution?

Comment: If you are newer to this subject, it might help to try their [official SDK](https://zenviasmsenus.docs.apiary.io/#reference/sdk's) instead which includes examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) and have the correct structure. Try this:

```
    $body = (object)[
        "from" => $from,
        "to" => $to,
        "contents" => [(object)[
                        "type" => "text",
                        "text" => $msg
                      ]]          
   ];           
   $campos = json_encode($body);
```

And then before you try to send it have a look at it with:

```
var_dump($campos);
```

Only when it looks **exactly** like the example can you actually try to send it.

Comment: Thank you very much KIKO Software.